# Azure web job CRON expression for different time slots for different days

Tags: cron, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-webjobs

I have azure webjob which is basically timer trigger type. I want to run this webjob different time slots for different days.
For example,  if I want to run azure webjob for Monday-Friday from 09:00pm to 06:00am following day and
if I want to run same webjob for saturday and sunday for entire day.
so, can you please let me know the CRON expression for above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

In your requirement, you need to write 2 CRON expressions. CRON expressions cannot be combined, so I think creating two webjobs, each with 2 expressions, can achieve your needs.

Comment: I'm aware of this approach. Please let me know any other way to complete this by one webjob